# Where can I find Airship alterations?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, eberron, vehicles

Where can I find alterations/improvements stats that PCs could make to a very basic airship?
Although I went (quickly) through "the forge of war", "explorer handbook" and the "campaign setting" I couldn't find any list of improvements and only very few suggestions ("life ring" p31 of explorer handbook).

Things like nets, harpoons, quick loading balistae?

Pathfinders references are welcomed here.

Comment: Do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Book "Stormwrack" has many details on ship to ship and ship to creature combat in water, but I would strongly look at "Spelljammer - concordance of arcane space". Those are the best two books that when combined with the others you mentioned you are pretty much set to build your own air fleet and battle.

Comment: Based on Spelljammer: http://www.spelljammer.org/ has some additional stuff and 3e conversions.